# Not able to check in project to Visual Studio Online due to missing files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm trying to check in an existing project to Visual Studio Online (VSO) for the first time but I keep getting errors due to missing files. These files appear to be items that we removed. I keep adding them to "Exclude" list but there are too many of them e.g. simple PNG images, JS files, etc.

I'm not sure where the "inventory" of files are kept in Visual Studio 2015.

Is there a quick and easy way to remove these missing files' records from Visual Studio so that I can check my project into VSO?

Comment: what type of errors? where do you see them?

Comment: I see them under "Team Explorer" and get the error messages when I try to check in my pending changes. Here's one of the errors I got:
Could not find file 'C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\de\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're correct that the error message you got is mainly caused when you're trying to check in files which are no longer exist on the machine.

You can go to Source Control Explorer -> select these missing files -> **Undo Pending Changes**, and then you don't need to exclude these missing files every time when you check in files.

Comment: Is there a way to see all missing files in one place or do I need to go folder by folder and select them one by one?

Comment: @Sam, I'm afraid you need to find the missing files one by one to do the "Undo Pending Changes" operation.